# FacetGrid of contour plots with custom z-index information

Tags: python, seaborn, facet-grid, contourf, kdeplot

Recently I attempted using seaborn to produce a contour plot. The only related function, `kdeplot`, seemingly only allows to visualize density of data, and it is not possible to provide custom z-index information.

Let me illustrate on a toy example: we have a function `f` with two independent variables `x, y` and a dependent variable `z`.

```py
def f(x: float, y: float) -> float:
    return x * y
```

I would like to construct a contour plot on `[0,1] \times [0,1]`.

Specifically in my case, I was trying to align multiple such plots in seaborn `FacetGrid`.

Let me know your experience in my case.

In pure matplotlib, the single contour plot can be implemented as follows.

```py
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# construct grid
N = 1000  # granularity
grid = np.linspace(0, 1, N, dtype='float32')

# evaluate function
z = map(lambda i: f(*i), itertools.product(grid, grid))

# plot
plt.contourf(
    grid,
    grid,
    np.array(list(z)).reshape((N, N)),
    100,
)
plt.show()
```

It is possible to embed matplotlib plots in seaborn `FacetGrid`, but I needed various workarounds to get even the most basic customizations of the facet. Several features I dealth with: custom ticks, unified styling (palette), shared color map, placing color bar.

At the end, I re-did everything using subfigures in matplotlib only, dropping seaborn.
I would have no problem, if `kdeplot` allowed specifying custom z-index information.

#### Conclusions

- It is not possible to produce contour plot in seaborn with provided z-index information.
- Working with matplotlib plots in seaborn `FacetGrid` is possible, but becomes very nasty.

I don't want this to sound like criticism of seaborn. I genuinely love the package, it squeezes so much of matplotlib and is so easy to use. I am just annoyed about the limitations I encountered in my case.

Comment: seaborn is a high-level api for matplotlib; a facetgrid is matplotlib subplots. There is little point in contorting your data / code to work with the seaborn API. In this case, working directly with the matplotlib explicit “Axes” interface, seems to be the best option.